# How do redirect API route to other API route in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, redirect, http-redirect

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and I have a situation where I have one deprecated API route for which if some tries to access that API route I need to **redirect** it to new API route.

Example:
GET /api/v1/getNames (deprecated API) --> GET /api/v2/getNames with a response code 308

Any ideas/examples how to do that? I'm trying to use RedirectResult() method but I'm still getting 200 response code with following body:

```
{
  permanent: true,
  preseveMethod: true,
  url: "/api/v2/getNames"
}
```

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
 [System.Web.Http.Route("/v1/getNames")]
 public IActionResult Get() {
 return new RedirectResult("/v2/getNames", true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use any code, since you are using attribute routing. Just add old route to a new  action

```
 [Get("/v1/getNames")]
[Get("/v2/getNames")]
 public IActionResult NewAction() 
.....
```